XML Requests in R. Long run time. More efficient way?
I have a code in R that runs perfectly fine. It just takes a very long time and i want to know if there is a way to improve its efficiency (Other type of request / converting data first...) .
I have a data table and for each row i need to search through a .xtf document to find the object with the ID contained in the data table. Then i need to extract attributes from this object. For a table with 14'000 entries and a xtf-file of 16'000 KB it takes me 2 hrs to run. Other code runs fast.
Here is my code:
# Find XTF
xtf_file <- list.files(path = input_dir, pattern = ".xtf$", full.names = TRUE)
# Read XTF (as XML)
xml_data <- read_xml(xtf_file)


# Use function for all TID's (the iteration is for a progress bar which i cut out here)
a_attributes_df <- data.frame(`SAA_PAA_from_xtf` = unlist(
  mapply(function(Tid, iteration) a_query_xtf_for_all(Tid, iteration), data_all$Tid, seq_along(data_all$Tid))
))


# The function
a_query_xtf_for_all <- function(Tid, iteration) {
  
  # XPath-Request based on TID
  xpath_query <- paste0("//*[@TID='", Tid, "']")
  
  # Find node in XML
  node <- xml2::xml_find_first(xml_data, xpath_query)
  
  # Initialise
  saa_paa <- NA
  
  if (!is.null(node) && xml2::xml_length(node) > 0) {
    
    # Extract attribute
    funktion_hierarchisch_node <- xml2::xml_find_first(node, ".//d1:FunktionHierarchisch", ns)
    if (!is.null(funktion_hierarchisch_node)) {
      funktion_hierarchisch <- xml2::xml_text(funktion_hierarchisch_node)
      
      # Check if SAA / PAA contained
      if (grepl("SAA", funktion_hierarchisch, ignore.case = TRUE)) {
        saa_paa <- "SAA"
      } else if (grepl("PAA", funktion_hierarchisch, ignore.case = TRUE)) {
        saa_paa <- "PAA"
      }
    }
  }
  return(c(`SAA/PAA` = saa_paa))
}

The XML Document looks like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<TRANSFER xmlns="http://www.interlis.ch/INTERLIS2.3">
  <HEADERSECTION VERSION="2.3" SENDER="UNKNOWN">
    ...
  </HEADERSECTION>
  <DATASECTION>
    <VSADSSMINI_2020_LV95.VSADSSMini BID="BASKET1">
        <VSADSSMINI_2020_LV95.VSADSSMini.Knoten TID="ch221714gDfKhSAa">
            <Baujahr>2024</Baujahr>
            <Bezeichnung>V1</Bezeichnung>
            <FunktionHierarchisch>SAA</FunktionHierarchisch>
        </VSADSSMINI_2020_LV95.VSADSSMini.Knoten>
        ...
    </VSADSSMINI_2020_LV95.VSADSSMini>
  </DATASECTION>
</TRANSFER>

data_all contains the coulmn "Tid" with values like: ch19yfb23ZpJZdD4
Your help is much appreciated!

So data_all$Tid contains strings like ch19yfb23ZpJZdD4? For each element of Tid there is an .xtf (or .xml?) document from which you want to extract either SAA or PAA  (<FunktionHierarchisch>...</FunktionHierarchisch>) if present? Btw, this does not match with the example ch221714gDfKhSAa from .xml. Are you able to merge/combine the .xml.files? The rest would be straightforward then. Match identifiers, extract information associated with the tag of interest.

If so, I do not see why we need mapply.

Consider creating a data frame of the XML, then merge it with data_all. This approach avoids the many-to-many iteration in R using for loops and XPath with // searching.
nodes <- xml_find_all(xml_data, "//d1:VSADSSMINI_2020_LV95.VSADSSMini.Knoten")

xtf_df <- data.frame(
    Tid = sapply(nodes, \(n) xml_text(xml_find_first(n, "@TID"))),
    SAA_PAA = sapply(nodes, \(n) xml_text(xml_find_first(n, "d1:FunktionHierarchisch")))
)


match_Tids <- merge(data_all, xtf_df, by = "Tid")

